# Pandas: Update DataFrame from incomplete boolean Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

```
>>> df1
              above below last_below
asn   country
12345 MX      6     3     1002000
      US      5     4     1006000
54321 MX      4     5     1004000
>>> df2
              above below
asn   country
12345 MX      1     0
54321 MX      0     1
      US      1     0
```

I update `df1` like so:

```
>>> df1 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
>>> df1
              above below last_below
asn   country
12345 MX      7.0   3.0   1002000.0
      US      5.0   4.0   1006000.0
54321 MX      4.0   6.0   1004000.0
      US      1.0   0.0         NaN
```

Now I want to update the `last_below` column to set it to the current time (we'll say `1008000` in my example here) ***if the `below` column was a `1` in `df2`***

I can get a list of all indexes for which the `below` column was a `1` in `df2` like so:

```
>>> below = df2.below == 1
>>> below
asn   country
12345 MX        False
54321 MX        True
      US        False
Name: below, dtype: bool
```

However if I try to use this Series to update `df1` I get an error:

```
>>> df1.loc[below, "last_below"] = time.time()
Traceback (most recent call laist):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../pandas/core/indexing.py", line 178, in __setitem__
    indexer = self.__get_setitem_indexer(key)
  File "/.../pandas/core/indexing.py", line 171, in __get_setitem_indexer
    raise IndexingError(key)
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: (asn   country
12345  MX       False
54321  MX        True
       US       False
Name: below, dtype: bool, 'last_below')
```

Just attempting to ***read*** `df1` and not update yields the following:

```
>>> df1[below]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../pandas/core/frame.py", line 1958, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/.../pandas/core/frame.py", line 1998, in _getitem_array
    key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
  File "/.../pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1939, in check_bool_indexer
    raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series provided as '
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

How can I align these indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC using `.loc`

```
df1.loc[below[below].index,'last_below']=1008000
df1
Out[607]: 
               above      below  last_below
asn   country                              
12345 MX         7.0        3.0   1002000.0
      US         5.0        4.0   1006000.0
54321 MX         4.0        6.0   1008000.0
      US         1.0        0.0         NaN
```